# what is the relationship/differences in among jquery, Knockoutjs, backbone.js?

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller, backbone.js, mvvm, knockout.js

I found that via google:

> Knockout is a JavaScript library that helps you to create rich, responsive display and editor user interfaces with a clean underlying data model.
>
> jQuery is a multi-browser ( cross-browser) JavaScript library designed to simplify the client-side scripting of HTML
>
> Backbone is a JavaScript library with a RESTful JSON interface and is based on the model–view–presenter (MVP) application design paradigm

Backbone is quite new term for me but I trying to connect some dots to visualize the concept. Can anyone help me on this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JQuery, simply put, is a utility library. JQuery abstracts away most of the common functionality you would do in JavaScript.  It has a very simple plug-in syntax that makes it easy for people to start using and offers cross browser compatibility support (i.e., getting JavaScript to work across browsers is difficult).  Examples of what you would do with JQuery would be to change the CSS class of div element or create a modal dialog box (refer to JQueryUI).

Knockout is used for data binding.  So you would be able to observe changes to a JavaScript object and be able to bind to HTML or changes to HTML element values and bind back to the JavaScript object.  So you when you update a property of a JavaScript object it will automatically cause the update to reflect in HTML.  I recommend watching the 20-minute [intro video].[1](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/MIX/MIX11/FRM08)

Backbone is a generic MVC(*) framework.  It's primary benefit is providing a structured way to manage your JavaScript code using an MVC/MVP pattern. It also has some good utilities.

All 3 JQuery, Knockout, and Backbone can be used together and do compliment each other.  If you are building a JS application of size, I would recommend looking at Angular.js though.  Angular.js can potentially address the concerns of all 3 (you may still use JQuery).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know Knockout. But about jQuery vs. Backbone.

First of all they are different things and may be used together. jQuery is used to manipulate the elements in your page, to deal with the page itself: its behaviour and content. For example: you make an element appear or disapear with jQuery.

About Backbone. It is used to structure your application and manipulates data from your server and display it (maybe with the help of jQuery). You create models, views and collections with backbone and use them to generate pages. This pages can be manipulated with jQuery.

Comment: Is backbone somehow works like Ajax?thank you for your reply though!

Comment: Backbone load data from the server, but it is just one of it features, it also manages the presentation of this data and the structure of your application in the fornt end.